# React native callling callback function

Tags: javascript, react-native, callback

I have a function on my custom component which is basiaclly a callback to re-render (this.setState()) the component from where it was called from.

I am struggling with the correct syntax of these calls. Can you please assist?

Custom component

```
export class LanguageSelector extends Component {

afterChange(callback: any){
    callback();
}
```

Other component where the LanguageSelector is imported:

```
<LanguageSelector afterChange={() => { this.setState({}) }} ></LanguageSelector>
```

[image]

LanguageSelector

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    View,
} from 'react-native';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import Flag from 'react-native-flags';
import { Global } from '../global'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export class LanguageSelector extends Component {



    afterChange(callback: any) {
        callback();
    }

    changeLang(lang: string) {
        Global.localizedStrings.setLanguage(lang);
        //this.setState({});
    }

    render() {
        return (

            <View style={{ paddingBottom: 10, flexDirection: "row", alignSelf: "flex-end" }}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.changeLang('de')}>
                    <Flag code="DE" size={32} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.changeLang('en-US')}>
                    <Flag code="GB" size={32} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>

        )
    }
}
```

Comment: In the other component you are not passing to `afterchange`a callback function to be executed; instead you are directly setting the state. You should have something like `afterChange={() => { this.setState({}) }}`.

Comment: You are right... But the same error is still there.

Comment: I am just a beginner with TypeScript but it seems to me you are missing the property `afterChange` in your 'LanguageSelector' interface.

Comment: It is there defined as a function

Comment: Can you share the code for the type definition of 'LanguageSelector', please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry was thinking you are using Typescript you have this option or just use this.props.afterChange() directly where you want.

```
interface LanguageSelectorProps{
   afterChange: () => void;
}
```

```
export class LanguageSelector extends Component<LanguageSelectorProps> {

     constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.afterChange = this.afterChange.bind(this);
    }

    afterChange() {
        this.props.afterChange(); // callback ,use whatever you want 
    }

    changeLang(lang: string) {
        Global.localizedStrings.setLanguage(lang);
        //this.setState({});
    }

    render() {
        return (

            <View style={{ paddingBottom: 10, flexDirection: "row", alignSelf: "flex-end" }}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.changeLang('de')}>
                    <Flag code="DE" size={32} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                    this.changeLang('de')
                    this.afterChange(); 
                 }>
                    <Flag code="GB" size={32} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>

        )
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please explain more

Comment: I am using typescript

Comment: why u have propTypes then

Comment: typo I guess. Not using it

Comment: this should fix how to call your callback and types issue

Comment: Check my original question. Callback should be passed from other component. Inthis case that is never called.

Comment: <LanguageSelector afterChange={() => { console.log("called") }} ></LanguageSelector>

Comment: I know use this.props.afterChange() in your LanguagueSelector will log called. Are you trying the solution ???

Comment: I have your example copied it is the same. I think you don't understand what I want to achieve. I want get the console.log("called")  to be called.

Comment: And even the afterChange in the LanguageSelector is not called....

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@anthowm/924a8c for me is working

Comment: OK I see now. I was missing this call: this.props.afterChange(). Works now.